# In-app purchase asks every time to sign-in Apple ID and password on IPAD specifically when installed from test flight

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, in-app-purchase-receipt

My app's IAP works fine on local build for iPhones and **IPAD** for **iOS 15.1** but when I upload it on a **test flight**, it keeps on displaying enter apple id and password even I have signed into it on the app store using a sandbox account.
This problem occurs only on iPad iOS 15.1 and works fine for every other device that too when I install the app from a test flight. When I take a local build from Xcode, the issue does not happen.

Comment: so how does apple test it when the app is in review? Do they sign in from the apple account and don't use the sandbox accounts?

Comment: How does apple test is not a question anybody here can answer but beta testers don't get issued sandbox accounts

Answer (score 1):

Use your real account not the sandbox for TestFlight

Comment: I signed in to the real account only and did not sign in sandbox account, it works fine but when I signed in using the real account and sandbox account both, it keeps on asking for it? is it an issue?

Comment: sandbox is not used for TestFlight only real accounts.

Comment: by real account, did you mean the beta tester account?

Comment: What ever iCloud account you use. Not the one listed under sandbox in App Store connect.

Comment: Alright. thanks for the guidance.